# error NU3034: Package '...' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': This package is signed but not by a trusted signer

Tags: nuget

As of today, this message seems unsolvable.
nuget.config is in
C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config

Setting signatureValidationMode to accept instead of 'required' does not make any difference. nuget Sync neither.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
  <trustedSigners>
    <author name="Microsoft2021">
        <certificate fingerprint="AA12DA22A49BCE7D5C1AE64CC1F3D892F150DA76140F210ABD2CBFFCA2C18A27" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="false" />
      </author>
      <repository  name="nuget.org" serviceIndex="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json">
       <certificate fingerprint="0e5f38f57dc1bcc806d8494f4f90fbcedd988b46760709cbeec6f4219aa6157d" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="true" />
       <certificate fingerprint="5a2901d6ada3d18260b9c6dfe2133c95d74b9eef6ae0e5dc334c8454d1477df4" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="true" />
      </repository>
  </trustedSigners>

</configuration>
```

ALL packages now are considered not trusted. You have any other hints? THANKS!

error NU3034: Package 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen 6.1.3' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': This package is signed but not by a trusted signer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was at the end quite simple.
Nuget.config can have different scopes, I thought were only two scopes, computer level and VS 2019(2017) level.
Untrue.
https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#config-file-locations-and-uses

The nuget.config in my solution was wrong. AFter removing it, packages were accepted again.